# WPF MVVM command canexecute enable/disable button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I want to enable RibbonButton when textbox property text isn't null. Disable RibbonButton when textbox property text is null. I want to use CanExecute method in ICommand for it. How can I do it?

**View:**

```
 <Custom:RibbonButton
                        LargeImageSource="..\Shared\img\save_diskete.png"
                        Label="Save"
                        Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">
                    </Custom:RibbonButton>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class KomentarViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Data
        private ICommand m_ButtonCommand;
        public ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return m_ButtonCommand;
            }
            set
            {
                m_ButtonCommand = value;
            }
        }
        private string textKomentar;
        public string TextKomentar
        {
            get
            {
                return this.textKomentar;
            }
            set
            {
                // Implement with property changed handling for INotifyPropertyChanged
                if (!string.Equals(this.textKomentar, value))
                {
                    textKomentar = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TextKomentar");
                }
            }
        }        
        private ObservableCollection<Komentar> allCommentsInc;
        public ObservableCollection<Komentar> AllCommentsInc
        {
            get
            {
                return allCommentsInc;
            }
            set
            {
                allCommentsInc = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllCommentsInc");
            }
        }

        public int idIncident { get; private set; }
        public Incident incident { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public KomentarViewModel(int id)
        {
            CC_RK2Entities context = new CC_RK2Entities();
            this.idIncident = id;

            AllCommentsInc = new ObservableCollection<Komentar>(context.Komentar.Where(a => a.Incident_id == idIncident));
            incident = context.Incident.Where(a => a.id == idIncident).First();

            //ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ShowMessage));
        }
        #endregion        

        #region Methods
        //ukaz napsany text
        public void ShowMessage(object obj)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(obj.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(this.TextKomentar);
        }
}
```

**RelayCommand**

```
namespace Admin.Shared.Commands
{
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _action;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;            
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
                _action(parameter);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I have enabled that for text box values earlier and the method I have implemented is shown down there

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to modify your RelayCommand class like this

```
  class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    private Func<bool> _func;  

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action,Func<bool> func)
    {
        _action = action;
        _func = func;
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if(CanExecuteChanged!=null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this,new EventArgs());
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_func != null)
           return _func();
        return true;
    }



    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Initialize ButtonCommand as

```
ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand((s) => ShowMessage(s),()=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextKomentar));
```

RaiseCanExcuteChanged from the setter of Text property

```
        public string TextKomentar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textKomentar;
        }
        set
        {
            // Implement with property changed handling for INotifyPropertyChanged
            if (!string.Equals(this.textKomentar, value))
            {
                textKomentar = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextKomentar");
            }
            ButtonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

implement this for canexecute:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {if(thistext available)
            return true; 
         else
            return false;  
        }
```

Since, `CanExecuteChanged` is raised when the `CanExecute` method of an `ICommand` gets changed. it gets invoked when some command that could change `canexecute`.
and can execute changed should be changed to this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
    add {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

in your view model constructor:

```
m_ButtonCommand= new RelayCommand(Submit, CanSubmit);

now method for this submit:
 private bool CanSubmit(object obj)
        {
            if(thistext available)
                return true; 
             else
                return false;  

        }
 public void Submit(object _)
  {//... code}

 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
```

**do it like this.**

Comment: But, how can I pass the text property of TextBox to the CanExecute method?

Comment: np please mark it as an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

In straightforward words, you need the following:

1. Let's first create our own `delegate` command:

```cs
public class DelegateCommand : DelegateCommandBase
{
    private Action _executeMethod;
    private Func<bool> _canExecute;
    
    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod)
        : this(executeMethod, () => true) {}
   
    public DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> _canExecute): base()
    {
        if (executeMethod == null || _canExecute == null) {         
              throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(executeMethod),      
                              Resources.DelegateCommandDelegatesCannotBeNull);
        }

        _executeMethod = executeMethod;
        _canExecute = _canExecute;
    }

    public void Execute() => _executeMethod();  
    public bool CanExecute() => _canExecute();
    
    protected override void Execute(object parameter) => Execute();
    protected override bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecute();

    public DelegateCommand ObservesProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        ObservesPropertyInternal(propertyExpression);
        return this;
    }
    
    public DelegateCommand ObservesCanExecute(Expression<Func<bool>> canExecuteExpression)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecuteExpression.Compile();
        ObservesPropertyInternal(canExecuteExpression);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here, `DelegateCommandBase` is actually from `Prism.Commands` namespace.

If you don't use [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/) as an MVVM framework for WPF, you can create your own copy of `DelegateCommandBase` (look for the solution [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Commands/DelegateCommandBase.cs)).

2. In your View Model, create a member with type `DelegateCommand` and initialize it in the constructor:

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
    private DelegateCommand _okCommand;
    public DelegateCommand OkCommand
    {
        get => _okCommand;
        set => SetProperty(ref _okCommand, value);
    }
        
    public MyViewModel() 
    {
        OkCommand = new PrismCommands.DelegateCommand(OkCommandHandler,
                                                      OkCanExecuteCommandHandler);
    }
    
    private void OkCommandHandler()
    {
        // ...
    } 
    
    // This is important part: need to return true/false based
    // on the need to enable or disable item
    private bool OkCanExecuteCommandHandler() =>
        return some_condition_to_enable_disable_item;   
}
```

**Note:** make sure to raise execution changed event, every time something changes that can affect `some_condition_to_enable_disable_item` condition behavior.

For example, in the case of [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/), you can call [`RaiseCanExecuteChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/gg405758(v=pandp.50)) method once a change happens related to the condition (in our case `OkCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`).

*Small hint: for Telerik WPF Controls, you need to call `InvalidateCanExecute()` instead of `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`*.

---

Finally, our `XAML` will look like this:

```xml
<Button x:Name="btnOk"
        Content="Ok"
        Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands` namesapce from `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll`. Class `DelegateCommand` has own `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method. So the benifit is you don't have to write yout own implementation of `ICommand`.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCanDoExportChecked}" />
    <Button Command="{Binding ExportCommand}" Content="Export" />
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DelegateCommand ExportCommand { get; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ExportCommand = new DelegateCommand(Export, CanDoExptor);
    }

    private void Export()
    {
        //logic
    }

    private bool _isCanDoExportChecked;

    public bool IsCanDoExportChecked
    {
        get { return _isCanDoExportChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (_isCanDoExportChecked == value) return;

            _isCanDoExportChecked = value;
            ExportCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool CanDoExptor()
    {
        return IsCanDoExportChecked;
    }
}
```