# CanExecute not called

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, command, controls

I have an assembly where I define Application wide commands in a class:

```
public class CtrlCommands
{
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand CtrlAddToFavourites = new RoutedUICommand("CtrlAddToFavourites", "CtrlAddToFavourites", typeof(CtrlCommands));
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand CtrlRemoveFromFavourites = new RoutedUICommand("CtrlRemoveFromFavourites", "CtrlRemoveFromFavourites", typeof(CtrlCommands));
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand CtrlNew = new RoutedUICommand("CtrlNew", "CtrlNew", typeof(CtrlCommands));
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand CtrlDelete = new RoutedUICommand("CtrlDelete", "CtrlDelete", typeof(CtrlCommands));
    public static readonly RoutedUICommand CtrlSearch = new RoutedUICommand("CtrlSearch", "CtrlSearch", typeof(CtrlCommands));
}
```

In my example, I generate a custom Control in Code (the Control derives from button) and assign the command (CtrlRibbonItem extends Button):

```
mainPage.CtrlRibbonItems.Add(new CtrlRibbonItem { CtrlIcon = "file", Content = "Neu", Command = CtrlCommands.CtrlNew});
```

The ribbon item will be always inactive and the canExecute Handler is never invoked.

In the app itself, the command gets wired up like so:

```
<mvvm:CtrlBaseUserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding x:Name="CtrlNewCommandBinding"
                    Command="commands:CtrlCommands.CtrlNew"
                    CanExecute="CtrlNewCommandBinding_OnCanExecute"
                    Executed="CtrlNewCommandBinding_OnExecuted"/>
</mvvm:CtrlBaseUserControl.CommandBindings>
```

When I use a normal WPF Button instead, everything works fine...

**UPDATE**
The problem was the commandbinding being defined in the UserControl.CommandBindings, while the CtrlRibbonItem is placed outside the UserControl (the Ribbon bar is part of the window, not the usercontrol)

Comment: You need to tell WPF that the 'CanExecute' status of the button has changed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31807332/wpf-mvvm-command-canexecute-enable-disable-button

Comment: I dont understand why this is not automatically done by wpf, since it works well for the Standard button, but not for my CtrlRibbonItem